# Ant regexp mapper: Reading patterns from a file?

Tags: regex, ant, mapper

I would like to write a generic Ant build script with a `<copy>` task that could optionally rename files based on regexps. A nested `<regexpmapper>` would load the renaming patterns from a project-specific properties files if it exists.

Has someone already done this or do I have to write an own mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might do this.

Project properties file `proj_props.txt` contains:

```
use.filter=regexp.mapper
from.regexp=(.*)_test(.*)
to.regexp=\\1\\2
```

(Note the escapes `\` in the to string.)

Buildfile:

```
<property file="proj_props.txt" />

<!-- filter for regexp -->    
<filtermapper id="regexp.mapper">
    <tokenfilter>
        <replaceregex pattern="${from.regexp}"
                      replace="${to.regexp}" />
    </tokenfilter>
</filtermapper>

<!-- identity filter, used when no regexp needed -->
<filtermapper id="identity.mapper" />

<!-- decide which filter to use -->
<condition property="chosen.mapper"
           value="regexp.mapper" else="identity.mapper">
    <isset property="use.filter" />
</condition>

<copy todir="...">
    <fileset>
       ...
    </fileset>
    <filtermapper refid="${chosen.mapper}" />
</copy>
```

You define a couple of [`filtermapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#filter-mapper) instances, one that carries out a regexp replace based on properties from the project properties file, the other that does nothing.  The `use.filter` property decides which gets chosen.  If the project properties file doesn't exist `use.filter` would not be set, so the 'do-nothing' identity filtermapper will be used.

Note that this only works when using nested resources in the `copy` task.  If you only have one file to copy, and use `<copy file="..."`, the filtermapper is ignored.